# Find multiple objects by name using Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating flight reservation system using `Spring MVC` and `Spring Security`, In this application I'm going to save multiple reservations for one user. Then if user logged into the system I want to show their reservation details. There are multiple records for one user in the database. Here is the simple form. (I'm using `Spring 4.1.6` and `Spring security 4.0.1` )

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User name</th>
                <th>Operations</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${us}" var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ${user.name}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${user.passengers}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the `controller`

```
@RequestMapping("/account/my-bookings")
public String showBookings(Model model, Principal principal){
    String name = principal.getName();
    model.addAttribute("us",reservationService.findAll(name));
    return "my-bookings";
}
```

Here is the `service class`

```
public List<FlightReservation> findAll(String name) {
    FlightReservation flightReservation = flightReservationRepository.findByName(name);
    return findAll(flightReservation.getName());
}
```

Here is the `repository`

```
public interface FlightReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<FlightReservation, Integer> {

    FlightReservation findByName(String name);

}
```

When I executing this, it gives several exceptions. If there is multiple records in the database, it gives `result returns more than one elements`. If there is only one record in the database for a user, there is a endless loop in console.

As a beginner, I appreciate your help to find out that I'm doing a wrong thing or what I need to do to get the reservation details into the table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of your repository method is wrong. Use a List or a Set. Having a singular return type works similarly to calling [getSingleResult](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult%28%29) on a JPA query, throwing an exception when multiple items are found.

Additionally the service method calls itself recurrently, when the repository returns a value. It should probably be implemented like this:

```
public List<FlightReservation> findAll(String name) {
    return flightReservationRepository.findByName(name);
}
```